# Description of flop as graded algebra

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, birational-geometry

I am looking for an example of a flop $Y \to X \leftarrow W$, possibly with exceptional locus at least a $\mathbb{P}^2$, where $X = \text{Spec } A$ is affine and $Y,W$ can be described as explicit graded $A$-algebras.

Comment: Check out these notes: http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/staff/G.Brown/reid.pdf. They contain a lot of examples (e.g. section 1.3) of what you are looking for.